what do you call a multi-mode form?
A bunch of apps forms with multiple modes:

a "view mode" with all of the data displayed in text form
an "edit mode" with all of the data displayed in <input> tags which allow the user to edit them

These forms will often have an Edit button which changes to a Save button when in "edit mode".
Sorry if this is a dumb question, but is there a name for this pattern? Googling "multi-mode form" brings up a bunch of "modal dialog" results

From your phrasing in the question I would say this is a pattern I've been calling Edit in place. UI patterns call it Inplace Editor. Although their examples are only for editing a single field, for me this pattern also contains editing the whole form in place.

Having an edit view and then a summary view for a form is usually done as a 2-step process.
This approach is quite useful because it allows users to verify their input before submitting. It adds a small friction in the submit process, which can prevent mistakes.
You can see this approach used in almost all banking apps, when making a money transfer, for example. You can also see this during checkout process in e-commerce.
Enforcing the summary view at the end is better than having a button to toggle beween the views, because users might simply miss it.
If you just put the toggle as optional feature, that's not common practice, so probably there isn't a name for it. Otherwise, it's called a multi-step form.

good tip - the form I have in mind is for much lower-stakes data than something like a bank transaction (what I have in mind can be edited unlimited times to correct any mistakes - think a user profile page with an "About me" section and Avatar image selector)
